color calculated for a selection by the Photoshop Average Filter
Where can I find the value of the color calculated for a selection by the Photoshop Average Filter?
After I apply the Average Filter to a selection and zoom into pixel scale, the info panel reads out a variety of HSB values for the individual pixels.
Is it possible to transfer the color calculated by the Photoshop Average Filter directly to the foreground color?
Is it possible to create a swatch based on the Average Filter color of a selection?
Here I've selected the reds in an image with Select Color Range fuziness 200 on red ff0000.  I've duplicated the selection to a new layer and applied the Average Filter.  The pixels all have different HSB values using the eyedropper with Point Sample selected.  My goal is to get the average HSB values for reds in this image.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What are you trying to achieve by doing this, and what is failing?  When I use the average filter, all the pixels it averages inside the selection are the same colour. You can use the Eyedropper tool in Photoshop to sample the colour.

Make sure to set the Sample Size of the Eyedropper Tool to Point Sample. If it has a big radius, the result might be affected by nearby pixels.

Thanks.  I have the eyedropper set to Point Sample and after applying the Average Filter, all the pixels have different HSB values.  I believe Average has applied transparency to the pixels, which is impacting the average HSB values.

I've added a screenshot above.  After applying the Average filter, the HSB values vary wildly.  I'd like to get the average value of reds in this image into a swatch.  Thanks.

Thanks for the update but I don't think the average filter will work properly when selecting by a colour range like this.  Essentially some of the pixels are selected and some are not, therefore it can't average the ones that aren't selected. Also I can see the image has semi-transparency, and the average filter doesn't take transparency into account.  Why are you trying to do this? What are you using it for?  Currently your question looks like an XY Problem

Thanks.  I also tried this.  After applying the Average Filter, I entered Quick Mask and applied Image - Adjustments - Threshold 5, which was the first value populated.  This should select all of the 100% opacity pixels.  I duplicated this selection to a new layer, inverted the selection, and executed Content Aware Fill to fill all of the transparent pixels with the color of the 100% opacity pixels, but for some reason, Photoshop made all the selected transparent pixels transparent.  Am I missing an easy way to get the color calculated by the Average filter into a swatch?

You still haven't answered my questions. Why are you doing it? What is this for?  The average filter only really works on fully opaque pixels, and regular selections - not selections where you choose only certain pixels.

I'd like to extract the color palette from an image.  When I use Save for Web, the Color Table generated for any particular color count appears to rely on the number of pixels utilizing a color, so for example, if there isn't much blue in the image, there won't be any blue in the Color Table.  I'd like to extract the average HSB for each color,  regardless of the frequency with which that color appears in the image.

I was able to get the Quick Mask, Image - Adjustments - Threshold 5 method to work by duplicating the selected pixels to a new layer and then transforming all of the opacity 100% pixels to X = 0 and Y = 0, so that I could find them.  Those pixels all have the same HSB, in this case the average red for the image.  I'd still be curious if I'm missing an easier way of finding the average red, blue, and green in an image.

But why are you trying to extract the colour palette from an image/find the average red/blue/green? What is the purpose of this? What is the problem you are ultimately trying to solve by doing this? What is it for? What is the ultimate goal, the bigger picture?

Thanks.  I've provided a more detailed explanation of my purpose below.

You should add those details to your question.  The way you want to do this will not really work IMO. It's a bad idea.  You've essentially asked the wrong question here. It would have been much better to just ask how to match colours for making composite images (your actual goal). Instead, you are asking about how to make your method work, when it isn't even suitable.  This is the very definition of an XY Problem.

If you'd asked the right question in the first place, or just mentioned what you were actually trying to do, I could have told you that Photoshop has a Match Color function which you can use for making composite images (matching the colours of one image based on another). Image > Adjustments > Match Color.  Instead we have gone through a whole pointless conversation where I repeatedly tried to find out what you are actually trying to do. And now we know, finally.

Thanks.  I also tried Match Color, but I wasn’t happy with the results when the color palettes included very different ranges of hues.  The Average color method seems to be working well, at least for my purposes.

Be advised that comments are not for extended conversations. Please use [chat] for this. For now, I will leave the comments as they are about the question mostly.

Your selection is fuzzy. The marquee line shows the 50% selection strength border. Applying effects to fuzzy selections make the calculation results also fuzzy. The average of a selection is the real average only if the selection has sharp edges.

The top line shows the selected area. The transform cage is turned ON to show the area better.
The middle line shows the result after applying the average filter. The selection was sharp.
The bottom line shows what the averaging gives if the selection is fuzzy. In this case the selection was feathered. The selection becomes easily fuzzy if it is based on color or generated from a mask. Convert your selection to layer mask and check if there's grey areas.
BTW. Not a slightest idea what's your actual goal. Revealing it could give something useful to reach it. In comments you wrote something about color palettes. Let Photoshop make the palette - turn the image to indexed mode.

Thanks.  My goal is to extract the color pallet from one image and apply it to another image for compositing.  I’ve found many methods that shift all of the colors in the target image based on brightness, for example shifting all of the shadows, mid tones, and highlights each to a single new color using Gradient Maps.  Instead, I’d like to shift hue and saturation of the target image to match that of the source image without affecting the brightness.

I’ve found that when I generate a color table from a source image with Save for Web, I might, for example get no blues if I extract 8 colors or I might get some random number of blues if I extract 256 colors.  Also, I’ve found that if I extract a 256 color color table from the source image, convert the target image to Indexed Color 8 bit, apply the 256 color color table, convert this image back to 16 bit, and blend it with the target image with a color blend mode, I get sharp edges between the hue transitions, probably because Indexed Color only supports 8 bit.

I’m open to suggestions for extracting a color pallet from an image and applying it to another image while shifting the hue and saturation based on the hue and saturation in the image, rather than the brightness.

Get Krita. It has advanced color curves. You can for example apply curves to hue or saturation. Krita allows curves and many other adjustments be "adjustment masks". That's essentially the same as adjustment layer in Photoshop. You can apply a good curve to a new image. I guess that's you wanted. Play a while with the curves to find the math facts how to retain the continuity. I mean how to avoid new unwanted sharp color borders. In addition Krita has G'MIC - a collection of effects (including color remixers), which gives to you a possibility to use a week only to find what's included.

Thanks.  I’ll take a look at Krita.  I hadn’t heard of it.  There are also a handful of LUT creation applications I plan on testing, although the ones I’ve looked at so far don’t take the colors in the target image into account, so I would think they will always be different from the source.

Adjusting the hue and saturation of the Average color of each target channel to match the Average color of the source seems to get the colors pretty close without pushing each tone to a single color.  Here I’ve shifted the colors in a Klimt painting first to a palette extracted from a Renoir, then to a palette extracted from a Rembrandt.



